Change background color of bootstrap button after dropdown selection
In my Flask web app I am using bootstrap 4 dropdown buttons where the html for one of the buttons looks like:
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" style="{{ buttoncolor }}" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Valdez
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('ak.valdez_stormtracker') }}">Storm Tracker</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('ak.valdez_seasontracker') }}">Season Tracker</a>
        </div>
      </div>

I would like the button's background color to change when the url of the page matches one of the url's of the dropdown options.
I have achieved this on regular buttons (no dropdown) as viewed here:
https://www.snowpacktracker.com/btac/
This is done by using custom.js with:
    // Handles the active state transition on bootstrap nav bar
    // get current URL path and assign 'active' class
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    console.log(pathname);

    $('.nav > li > a[href="'+pathname+'"').children().addClass('active')

And with some custom css:
.btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
  background-color: var(--color);
}

In this case, the button is wrapped in an <a> tag:
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="{{ btnurl }}">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary" style="{{ buttoncolor }}">{{btntxt}}</button>
            </a>
          </li>

I am unable to find a similar solution that will work for the dropdown case. Although recognizing the URL similar to above would be ideal, it would probably also work just to change the background color of the button if any dropdown item is clicked (and retain the color when the new URL is loaded).

Javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
// Get the current URL path
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
console.log(pathname);
// Check if the current URL matches any dropdown item
$('.dropdown-menu a').each(function() {
    var linkUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    if (linkUrl === pathname) {
        // Change the button's background color
        $('#dropdownMenuLink').addClass('active');
    }
});
// Change the button's background color when a dropdown item is clicked
$('.dropdown-menu a').on('click', function() {
    var clickedUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#dropdownMenuLink').addClass('active');
    // Optionally, you can store the clicked URL in localStorage or sessionStorage
    localStorage.setItem('activeDropdownUrl', clickedUrl);
});
// On page load, check if there's an active URL stored
var activeUrl = localStorage.getItem('activeDropdownUrl');
if (activeUrl) {
    $('#dropdownMenuLink').addClass('active');
}
});

CSS
.btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active {
background-color: var(--color); /* Change this to your desired color */
}


This solution works for the first dropdown button I have (of three total). But if I click on any of the dropdown selections on the other two buttons, just the first button keeps the background color. I can post my full html for all three buttons if useful.

I was able to make a variation of your code work (also using @Yogi comment solution). I added a unique id to each of my three class="dropdown" div elements (for each button). Then I am able to run ("#btndiv1 a.dropdown-item").each(function ())  three times consecutively within (document).ready(function(), for each id. If there is a match with the href and pathname (or endsWith(pathname)), then I .addClass("active") for both the unique id of the button and for the dropdown selection (this). Maybe not the most efficient way to check all buttons, but works and seems fast.
